# Power BI DAX Query to get Weekly Total View

Tags: powerbi, dax

need help in writing a DAX query to create a Table view in Power BI

[image: Data]

As you can see above, I have a Table - which has cities and dates with Sales count, I want to create a view with single record per city and sales count of all its occurrences in that week ending on Saturday.

So far i have written this ('Data Sheet' is the name of the excel I am reading data from ...)

```
WeeklySalesCount = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE(
        DataSheet,
        DATESBETWEEN(
            CALENDAR(MIN(DataSheet[Date]), MAX(DataSheet[Date])),
            [Date] - WEEKDAY([Date], 2) + 1,
            [Date] - WEEKDAY([Date], 2) + 7
        )
    ),
    "Location", InvIssue[Location],
    "Sales", InvIssue[Sales]
)
}
```

but power gives me error saying, it cannot find this column date: Any other idea, as how to create this table using a DAX measure???

Answer (score 0):

First populate 'End of Week' calculated column

```
End of Week = Data[Date]+7-WEEKDAY(Data[Date]-7)
```

[image]

Then use summarize dax function to get desired Table.

[image]

```
Table = SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[Location], Data[End of Week], "SlaesBYWeek", SUM(Data[Sales]))
```